# Can't find prism extension in VS 2019 for Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, prism

Got issue when trying to find `Prism Framework` and `Prism Template Pack` in extension via Visual Studio 2019 for Mac in `Visual Studio > Extensions > Gallery Tab`.  Tried these of this online repository url(s) below but none of them works.

- https://prism.azureedge.net/main.mrep
- https://addin.prismlibrary.com/main.mrep

Does anyone knew the right repository url or the extensions to use so that I can download the `Prism Template Pack` into my VS 2019 for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not yet available. Support for VS Mac 2019 is still in the works, and will hopefully land in the next couple of weeks. You can track the issue here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1755

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response.  Hope next week will get the prism extension up and running.  Thanks :)

Comment: What about this one (written 2 years before your comment) - https://dansiegel.net/post/2017/08/30/prism-template-pack-in-visual-studio-for-mac

Comment: They changed to much. I haven’t had the time to update it for vs2019. It’s on my todo list but will only be available for my GitHub sponsors.